# Can LINQ BeginTransaction works with new Context?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, transactions

My project is using Ninject to develop, for example, I wrote 2 functions to Insert or Update to Database

```
public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository {

    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public PersonRepository(DbContext context) {
        _context = context;
}

    public void InsertToDB(Person obj) {
        _context.Persons.Add(obj);
        _context.SaveChanges();
}   

    public void UpdateToDB(Person obj) {
        _context.Persons.Attach(obj);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }   
}
```

And in Controller, I declare the same DbContext and using transaction:

```
public class PersonController : Controller {

    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly IPersonRepository _repository;

    public PersonController(DbContext context, IPersonRepository repository) {
        _context = context;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExecuteToDb(Person person1, Person person2) {
        using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)) {
            try {
                _repository.InsertToDB(person1);
                _repository.UpdateToDB(person2);

                transaction.Commit();
            } catch (Exception) {
                transaction.RollBack();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if `InsertToDB()` or `UpdateToDB()` throw any exception, can transaction rollback?

I worry about it because I think the _context of Controller and Repository are different, I am not able to test it right now, help me, thanks!

Comment: `SaveChanges` commits, so if an exception is thrown the changes will not persist. Isn't it so?

Comment: @JNF yes, I want all operations rollback if an exception is thrown :)

Comment: I meant, your code already does that, as far as I can tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options here.  First, you can configure Ninject to use the same instance of DbContext for both your PersonController and your PersonRepository.  You do this by configuring your binding to use InRequestScope().  Then, you can call BeginTransaction and it's the same context.

Alternatively, you could just add BeginTransaction, CommitTransaction, and RollBackTrasaction methods to our IRepository class, and implement these in your Repository.

A third option is to just create a new TransactionScope() rather than calling BeginTransaction on the context.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
       new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, 
                                Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout }))
{
    _repository.InsertToDB(person1);
    _repository.UpdateToDB(person2);

    // if exception occurs, Complete will not get called, so transaction
    // is automatically rolled back when Dispose is called when using()
    // goes out of scope.  If Complete is called, then Commit is called.
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used TransactionScope but it have had some problems about connection, and TransactionScope don't have `Commit()` or `Rollback()`, just have `Complete()`.

Follow your guide, I added to my NinjectWebCommon.cs to instance the same DbContext: `kernel.Bind<DbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();`. Is this true?

Comment: @KenPlus - Sorry, you don't need to call Rollback or Commit, All you need is Complete.  If an exception is generated, then a rollback automatically occurs because Complete doesn't get called.  But yes, what you did with InRequestScope works